# How to Uninstall Ubuntu that's triple-boot with Win8 and another Ubuntu version

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have Windows 8.1, Ubuntu x64 and Ubuntu x86 installed on my PC.

On boot, the main selection is Ubuntu x64

I want to uninstall Ubuntu x64 now and change the boot menu selection to Ubuntu x86. Ofcourse, still dual-boot with Windows 8.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?
Or how to move the bootloader to a different partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Ubuntu X86 live usb, boot from live usb, delete the ubuntu x64 partition and use grub-repair. To grub-repair use the graphical method in the following link http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: it says W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: I'm running Trusty Tahr. The http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages won't work. I changed the trusty to saucy so http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages. And it installed and worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is kind of troublesome but it has solution. I have done this many times. I hope it works for you.

1 - Download an ubuntu .iso, and burn it to a dvd (ubuntu desktop versions do not fit on a cd nowadays).

2 - Boot your computer and choose the CD/DVD boot method where your Ubuntu Install disk is on.

3 - Select Try Ubuntu instead of install it, this will avoid some troubles because you will have to take further actions.

3.5 - before deleting the partition you want, first be sure to back up the data. We know that the partition that is deleted is lost forever. You can mount the partition, look for your files, and use an externadl HDD or a big USB, depending on the data you need to back up.

4 - In the Live CD session look for gparted, look for your Ubuntu x64 parition and delete it. It will leave you a free space, you can use the extra partition in the way you want.

5 -  Open a Console and type the next:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

this will show you all the partitions you have right away.

Lets think that your Ubuntu x32 is on **/dev/sda3**, you will have to mount that partition in order to access the grub, the option screen that let you select the OS partitons some seconds before you turn on the computer.

6 - Type the next commands one per each line
 `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /mnt`

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys 

sudo chroot /mnt
```

7 - Now you have to regenerate the Grub, to make possible to get the active partitions that you need

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

7B - If last step does not work, then try the next ones (It is the old school)

```
sudo update -grub2

sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

8 - time to finish

```
exit


sudo reboot
```

Have a nice booting :-)

Source --> [It is in Spanish, but It works](http://www.ubuntuleon.com/2012/11/recupera-el-grub-en-ubuntu-1204-y-1210.html)

Comment: it says mount point does not exist on sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot  @Barz

Comment: /dev/sda3 / is an example, you have to see where is the Partition of ubuntu you want to mount with the 

`sudo fdisk -l`