# How to safely delete a second Ubuntu installation that I don't need

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and installed 20.04 alongside, in a new partition. However I now realize that this is a mistake. All data is still in 18.04 and 20.04 is empty, it is not an update as I mistakenly assumed. I now understand that I must wait for the dot version of 20.04, to update my former version. My question is: How can I safely delete the new partition with 20.04 again?

Comment: If you don't want to wait, you can force 18.04 to 20.04 today.... https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-04-lts-to-20-04-lts-today    My system is dual boot, one is 18.04, and the other is *groovy* (it sits on the development cycle). I copied most of my wanted data from /home on the LTS (18.04) system to my *devel* system, other data sits on a NFS share that both access (ie one location used by both so not two copies).  It's my way of having two systems (I like two should i have problems with one also).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Uninstall Ubuntu that's triple-boot with Win8 and another Ubuntu version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485306/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-thats-triple-boot-with-win8-and-another-ubuntu-version)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want two systems so I am searching for a way to uninstall one installation and boot from the other, instead of Grub rescue complaining about missing partition

Comment: Thanks. I just tried the link that Karel referred me to: how to repair grub2 when ubuntu won't boot. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Start by backing up any important data. Make sure you boot into the 18.04 install and run GParted. Identify the partition with the 20.04 install. If you are running the 18.04 install its partition(s) will be locked. Select the 20.04 install and delete. Don’t be tempted to delete any other partitions that you are unsure of.

If you go ahead with the upgrade to 20.04 it’s a good idea to get 18.04 fully upgraded first.

Comment: I deleted the 20.04 partition with GPartEd. Now the computer does not start up anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I pressed enter too soon. I get a blank screen with: No such partition, entering rescue mode. I searched AskUbuntu for solutions but every time I ended up with a missing file error. I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 from the USB stick and now I have two systems again. So I aam back at the same problem: How to safely remove 20.04. Do you have an idea? Thanks

Comment: Just to let you know that it is now solved by repairing Grub after deleting the partition, according to instructions for "how to repair grub2 when ubuntu won't boot"